# Socket.io listening two NuxtJs apps

Tags: express, socket.io, nuxt.js

I have two NuxtJs with Socket.io installed. Both has same code for the server but has different ports, one is `1010` and the other one is `3000`. I created NuxtJs app with port `1010` firstly and the other NuxtJs app with port `3000` secondly.

But the socket.io on the NuxtJs app with port `1010` listening both NuxJs apps events and the socket.io on the NuxtJs app with port `3000` is not listening any event. I can't figure out what is going on?

NuxtJs app  with port `3000`

```
const express = require('express')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()
const host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.set('port', port)

// Listen the server
const server = app.listen(port, host)
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
```

NuxtJs app  with port `1010`
the same code here but the port is different

```
...
const port = process.env.PORT || 1010
...
```

Comment: Changing `host` even not working

Comment: I changed port `3000` to `1010` then start working but it is working on on `1010` port

Comment: Both of them are fresh NuxtJs apps

Comment: what is the port number on the `.env` file?